# Separate special rows of text file

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I have a text file like this:

```
   a 20 100  
   b 10 150
   c 30 400
```

I want to separate rows where the value of column 2 is equal to or less than 20 and value of column 3 is equal or greater than 100. I tried this code:

```
s_t1=20
e_t1=100
s_t=(`awk '{printf "%15.10g", $2}' a.txt`)
e_t=(`awk '{printf "%15.10g", $3}' a.txt`)
numb=`more a.txt|wc|awk '{print $1}'`;
iii=0
while [[ $iii -lt $numb ]]; do
  if [[ $s_t[$iii] -le $s_t1 ]]  && [[ $e_t[$iii] -ge $e_t1 ]]; then
    awk -v l=$iii 'FNR==l' a.txt >> out.txt
  fi
  iii=$(($iii+1))
done
```

but I have this error:

```
 syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "[0]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to access an array element with `$s_t[$iii]` when it should be accessed with `${s_t[$iii]}`. `${s_t[iii]}` would actually work as well, as the subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression.

Once this is fixed, there is another bug in your script: array indices start at zero, but awk record numbers start at 1, so when you find a matching line at array index 0, you try to print line 0 in awk, but that doesn't exist, so your program only returns the first line instead of the first two.

To fix *that*, your line

```
awk -v l=$iii 'FNR==l' a.txt >> out.txt
```

has to be replaced by

```
awk -v l=$(( iii + 1 )) 'FNR==l' a.txt >> out.txt
```

What your program does is way, way too complicated. You can do what you want with

```
awk '$2<=20 && $3>=100 { print }' a.txt
```